# How to redirect with header location in php when using ob_start?

Tags: php, header, location, ob-start

```
<?php

ob_start();

echo "<body><p>Hello "

if ($condition) {
   header( "Location: http://www.google.com/" );
   exit;
}

echo " World!</p></body>";
ob_end_flush();

?>
```

When `$condition` is true I get this:

```
<body>Hello
```

What I want is when `$condition` will be true then go to Google!!!

I don't know what is happening, can you explain or give me a solution!?

Thanks.

Comment: IMO, ob_start() can be done away with

Comment: I can't delete ob_start() because I need to process the output before write to the client.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `ob_end_clean();` before the header call.

Answer (score 2):

Everything should work, just put an `;` after echo "`<body><p>Hello`" and you will be fine..

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would have started what might go wrong first then do the processing.

An example

```
$exit_condition_1 = some_value1;
$exit_condition_2 = some_value2;

if($exit_condition_1 == false){

     //Redirect
     //Exit

}

if(!$exit_condition_2){

     //Redirect
     //Exit

}


//start the buffer ob_start()

//show some HTML

//flash the buffer ob_end_clean()

there is no point of starting the buffer then if something goes wrong close it and redirect. Just do value testing at the begining then process the request.

An example: lets say that you want to view a product's info and you have a function that will do that


function view_product($product_id){

   if(!$product = getProductById($product_id)){

        //product does not exist, redirect
   }


   if(the user does not have enough access rights){

     //show a message maybe 
     //redirect
   }


   //everything is alright then show the product info

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve a similar situation where a function was using ob_start() and there was `header("Location: http://www.example.com");` after that but erring "*already sent...*", I replaced the `header(...` call with

```
echo "<script> window.location.href = 'https://www.example.com' </script>"
```

and it worked in that particular case (all that was needed was a just page redirect anyway).