# Unable to redirect using header() I have tried in the code below

Tags: php, html

Unable to redirect using `header()` I have tried the following code by different ways same code is working in another file but in this file is not.
It's deleting the record and staying on this page not redirecting to the dashboard page.

```
<?PHP 
ob_start();
error_reporting(0);
session_start();

include 'config.php';

if (!empty($_POST))
{
    require 'config.php';
    // Delete Data
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    //$SCID=$_POST['subcategory_id'];
    $sql =mysql_query("DELETE FROM jobseeker WHERE jobseekerid= '$id'");
    $_SESSION["errmessage"] = "The Record Is Deleted..";
    header("location:dashboard.php");
}                         

ob_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_ functions. They are deprecated and will be removed in future PHP versions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect with header location in php when using ob\_start?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823130/how-to-redirect-with-header-location-in-php-when-using-ob-start)

Comment: use mysqli instead of mysql and  try giving a space between : and dashboard.php like so header("location: dashboard.php");

Comment: Try it with error reporting turned on, maybe there is a warning or an error.

Answer (score 0):

<s>From the [location header specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) :</s>

> The field value consists of a single absolute URI.

You use a relative url.

**Edit** : Relative urls are fine, rfc2616 I linked to has become obsolete.

I would also add a space after the colon to separate header name and value as in the [php examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

If this does not help, use tools like Firebug or Wireshark to see what the server sends out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it using javascript:

```
echo "<script>location.href = 'dashboard.php';</script>";
```